# How to create Android Fancy Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

How can I create a fancy tab like one in the mock-up screen either with tabhost or any other layout?

Where can I begin?

[image]

**This is what I've done so far with CODE**

[image]

I've no idea on how create floating look.

Comment: try to make image like what you want and set it.............

Answer (score 0):

see its Not default tab. In this pic they customized that tab, so Actually its an image. so in each and every tab you can set background image for that tab and you get that fancy tab.

Comment: What I have uploaded an mock up image and what I've completed so far.